# How to determine http message end?

Tags: python, sockets, http

I need to write simple http caching proxy with python socket class (not using SimpleHTTPServer class). The simple scheme is:

```
-open socket
-get http message
-check if we have cached resource
-either provide cached resource or re-request it from remote server
-close socket
```

When getting a message I use synchronous recv method:

```
38                 message = ""
39                 BUF_SIZE = 4096
40                 while 1:
41                         chunk = connection.recv(BUF_SIZE)
42                         if None == chunk or 0 == len(chunk):
43                                 break
44                         message += chunk
45                         print "rec %i" % (len(message))
```

And when I connect to my proxy with a browser, the browser will hold the socket open until it either gets response or I manually cancel the wait, which is perfectly by according to how HTTP is intended to work. So, my control is stuck at recv.

-I cannot just read say 1000bytes, coz I don't know how large the actual message is? There doesn't seem to be any message end mark in http?

-the program cannot continue while having open socket, using synchronous read;

-I could use either threads or some kind of async api, to solve control blocking, but this doesn't help with the problem to understand when to stop reading request and start handling it.

Comment: Valdimir Ilyich, yes, you need to implement proper HTTP protocol. In particular, you need to parse Chunk-Encoding.

Comment: And if Chunk-Encoding is not enabled by client, like in my case??

Comment: Chunks are part of HTTP 1.1, if client don't use them, client is not HTTP 1.1 compatible and is using HTTP 1.0, so there would be Content-Length header.

Comment: Don't understand how Content-Length could help, if it applies to body, while I need to read status line and headers to start with (e.g. for GET request)

Comment: You read headers until you read an empty line.

Comment: Check out the Python `http` package source for an example of HTTP message handling and parsing, specifically the methods of [http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/http/server.py#L386). Also [RFC 7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3).